# Dropping of terms in an expression in a certain limit in the presence of the complex/imaginary unit

Tags: complex-numbers, approximations

I have the following expression

$$
\frac{\sqrt{\delta_{0}}}{\delta_{0}+i\omega_{s}}
$$

If $\delta_{0}\ll1$, can I simply drop the $\delta_{0}$ in the denominator? Leading to

$$
-i\frac{\sqrt{\delta_{0}}}{\omega_{s}}
$$

? I was under the assumption that you can drop the $\delta_{0}$ from $\delta_{0} + \omega_{s}$, not $\delta_{0} + i\omega_{s}$.

Please advise.

Comment: can you provide more context?

Comment: @GattuMytraya Thank you for your feedback, $\delta_{0}$ is simply a dimensionless parameter, representing loss tangent of a transmission line. $\omega_{s}$ is simply the frequency of the signal mode traveling in the transmission line.

Comment: I am under the impression that the validity of dropping the term is more closely related to math than physics. But I'm not sure

Comment: @kowalski If $\delta_0$ is dimensionless and $\omega_s$ has dimensions of frequency, then the expression is already dimensionally inconsistent.

Comment: @J.Murray My apologies for the poor clarification. $\omega_s$ is a dimensionless-frequency, such that $\omega_s = \omega_{s}^{\prime}/\omega_{0}$ where $\omega_{0}$ is some normalization frequency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. Note that
$$\frac{\sqrt{\delta_0}}{\delta_0+i\omega_s} = \frac{(\delta_0-i\omega_s)\sqrt{\delta_0}}{\delta_0^2 + \omega_s^2} = \frac{\delta_0^{3/2}}{\delta_0^2+\omega_s^2} - i \frac{\delta_0^{1/2}\omega_s}{\delta_0^2 + \omega_s^2} \longrightarrow \frac{\delta_0^{3/2}}{\omega_s^2} - i \frac{\delta_0^{1/2}}{\omega_s}$$
in the limit as $\delta_0/\omega_s\rightarrow 0$.  If we define $\delta_0/\omega_s \equiv x$, then the expression becomes
$$\longrightarrow \frac{x^2 - i x}{\sqrt{\delta_0}}$$
To lowest order in $x$, this indeed just becomes $-ix/\sqrt{\delta_0} = -i\sqrt{\delta_0}/\omega_s$.  Whether it is acceptable to discard the (higher order) real part depends on the context.

An alternative expression would be
$$\longrightarrow -i \frac{x}{\sqrt{\delta_0}}\left(1+ix\right)\approx -i\frac{x}{\sqrt{\delta_0}} e^{ix} = -i\frac{\sqrt{\delta_0}}{\omega_s}e^{i\delta_0/\omega_s}$$
so you could view the next order correction as a small phase rotation.